# I've Leveled Up! - Leveling System for Arqade

Tags: discussion, reputation

We all love to gain <del>experience</del> rep here on Arqade, but wouldn't it be great if that translated into a [leveling system](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/343/15643)? Don't you just want to see your experience bar build up as you answer more questions and gain more <del>super powers</del> privileges?

Well wait no more! Through this special online only offer, you can now have an experience bar of your own! Before you know it, you'll have a user bar that looks like this!

[image: Boy howdy, does that look great!]

But wait, that's not all! With this offer, you'll also get the wonderful added bonus of converting other users reputation to levels as well. You can have fun everywhere.

[image: Coolamoondo]

Now all your friends will look just as cool as you!

Act now, and this offer will be yours for the low introductory price of $Free.99* and we'll even include shipping and handling**. Simply click the links below to get your copy today!

- [GreaseMonkey (for Firefox Users)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
- [Install Script](http://imgineme.com/IveLeveledUp/Ive_Leveled_Up!.user.js)
- [Project Page](http://imgineme.com/project/levelup)
- [On Github](https://github.com/ktsashes/I-Leveled-Up)

<sub>Some Chrome users have reported difficulty installing. If you are having troubles, click [here](http://imgineme.com/IveLeveledUp/Ive_Leveled_Up!.user.js) and watch the thing download. It'll tell you you can't install it directly. Go to `chrome://chrome/extensions/`, drag the extension from your download bar and drop it onto the page.</sub>

<sub>When updating make sure you delete the previous version of I've Leveled Up from your Downloads folder before you grab the new one, or the file will be saved as `Ive_Leveled_Up!.user (1).js`, while Chrome expects `.user.js` files.</sub>

<sub>* - $Free.99 is not an actual price. Any similarities to an actual price are coincidental and should be ignored.</sub>
<sub>** - Shipping and handling is transportation via the internet only. I will not ship you a real box. That would be stupid.</sub>

Comment: Woo! Level 91!!

Comment: I demand a real box! And also a refund!

Comment: I bought this for $expensive.99 and now it's on sale?!  Stupid internet pricing...

Comment: I clicked all three links and yet I don't have any levels >:O

Comment: @OrigamiRobot What browser are you using?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The first link in the list should take you to something that you can install if you are using Either Chrome, or FireFox with GreaseMonkey Installed. Should probably add links to those as well...

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Haha, I see. Well this is for levels on Arqade, not on robots.

Comment: Does this work with [Opera UserJS](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/)? I tried running *Ive_Leveled_Up!.user.js* with Opera 12.00, 64-bit build, as a User JavaScript but nothing seems to happen. Also, the 'Add Comment' button stops working.

Comment: I am guessing that [great minds](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/ive-leveled-up-leveling-system-for-arqade) [think alike](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5368418#5368418)!

Comment: I cannot believe someone actually -1'd this.

Comment: I guess I'm too dumb to install this in Firefox or IE. *sad face*

Comment: @EBongo Do you have [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) installed on Firefox?

Comment: This game better have a more satisfying ending than ME3.

Comment: Greasemonkey did the trick for Firefox.  Woot!

Comment: Only works on arqade.com? :(.

Comment: @JamesJiao Yes, it is a Arqade exclusive script for now. I could maybe open it up to other SE sites, but for now it is just for Arqade. It is the best fit here anyway. If you have greasemonkey, you can add the other sites to be included in your user specific settings for the script (done via the greasemonkey menu)

Comment: I can't see the little level icon on Chrome at work (behind a proxy filter).  Is the icon defined in the script, or is it loaded from some other server?  If the latter, that particular website might be blocked by the filter.

Comment: @MBraedley It is defined in the script as an SVG, and inline SVG is not quite supported on Chrome. There is ways to work around the problem, but I haven't implemented it yet, so it falls back to the text icon (or it should).

Comment: @Ktash: Recently switched to Chrome at home, and I'm still having the same issue.  Is there a workaround I can implement on my end?

Comment: @MBraedley Just implemented an update to the script. You should be able to reinstall it and see the icon.

Comment: @Ktash: Yep, that did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Last Update

Version: 3.4

- Fix for script not running in latest FF + Greasemonkey

**NOTE:** Updating from version 3.3 or below requires a manual update. Unfortunately, Greasemonkey made a breaking change to the script.

### Currently Known Issues

Report in comments or as an answer on this question

- Animation to show rep fades out in Chrome, but never fades in with the proper text

### How Levels Work

Many levels map to privileges earned on the site, and some are calculated in between privileges. Below is a chart of all levels you can currently earn using this script.

```
1 : 1
2 : 3
3 : 5
4 : 7
5 : 10
6 : 12
7 : 15
8 : 18
9 : 20
10 : 25
11 : 30
12 : 35
13 : 40
14 : 45
15 : 50
16 : 60
17 : 75
18 : 82
19 : 92
20 : 100
21 : 108
22 : 116
23 : 125
24 : 150
25 : 175
26 : 200
27 : 225
28 : 250
29 : 275
30 : 300
31 : 325
32 : 350
33 : 375
34 : 400
35 : 450
36 : 500
37 : 550
38 : 600
39 : 650
40 : 700
41 : 800
42 : 900
43 : 1000
44 : 1100
45 : 1250
46 : 1337
47 : 1450
48 : 1600
49 : 1750
50 : 2000
51 : 2150
52 : 2300
53 : 2500
54 : 2750
55 : 3000
56 : 3250
57 : 3500
58 : 4000
59 : 4500
60 : 5000
61 : 5500
62 : 6000
63 : 6500
64 : 7000
65 : 7500
66 : 8000
67 : 8500
68 : 9000
69 : 9500
70 : 10000
71 : 11000
72 : 12000
73 : 13000
74 : 14000
75 : 15000
76 : 16000
77 : 17000
78 : 18000
79 : 19000
80 : 20000
81 : 22000
82 : 25000
83 : 29000
84 : 34000
85 : 39000
86 : 44000
87 : 49000
88 : 54000
89 : 60000
90 : 66000
91 : 72000
92 : 79000
93 : 86000
94 : 93000
95 : 100000
96 : 110000
97 : 120000
98 : 130000
99 : 140000
100 : 150000
```

Comment: What do you do when you max out at 100,000 rep?  Do you just MF on Mephesto like in Diablo 2 or grind Inferno Act IV like Diablo 3?  Or grind until you can kill the LK like in WoW:WoTLK?

Comment: I installed on Chrome with no issues.

Comment: @Falcon165o !teekS noJ ,em taefed tsum uoy ,emag eht niw oT

Comment: Who's Jon Skeet ?

Comment: I agree.  Who the hell is Jon Skeet and what level can I grind and MF him?

Comment: He's the [end boss of Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), of course! He's level 214 by the formula.

Comment: Jon Skeet would be an [even more impossible boss than Chuck Norris](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134). I have to make it so that you can actually finish the game ;)

Comment: @Ktash The most impossible boss in the world would be Mr. Boshy of "I wanna be the boshy" :D

Comment: @Tacroy Jon Skeet is OP.  That is all I can say

Comment: I love the 2.0 update. :)

Comment: Loved the 3.0 easter egg :D

Answer (score 9):

Surely levels should equate with privileges?

Level 1 == 1 rep
Level 2 == 5 rep

etc...

Comment: They match closer now. Not 1-to-1 since there are more levels than privileges but still match up.

Answer (score 3):

I do like the idea of levels to spice everything up.  I would think for the first couple levels or so it should be equal to privileges:

For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/

Level 1 == 1 Rep (create post)

Level 2 == 5 Rep (Meta)

Level 3 == 10 Rep (Vote up, create wiki)

Level 4 == 20 Rep (Talk in chat)

Level 5 == 50 Rep (Comment everywhere

But where there is massive gaps for example View Closed Votes (250 rep) and Retag Questions (500 rep) make equal steps of like 50 between them.  So for example say View Closed Votes was Level 10, than 11 == 300 Rep, 12 == 350 Rep.

Of course this idea of '50' breaks when you get up to 20,000 points needed to Protect Questions, but doing viable steps in between massive jumps would make leveling fun in the Arqade :)

Answer (score 3):

My only beef with it is that I can't see anyone's rep anywhere anymore ever. I like being able to see their level but I also like seeing their rep. (I want ALL the information. I am greedy like that.)

Comment: When I add options, I'll make sure to add some ability to change this. Maybe fade between the two on a timer or something :)

Comment: @Ktash oooh, now you are just thinking all fancy! :D

Comment: Mouseover the level and you can see the rep.

Comment: @JoethePerson Oh, nifty! Thanks!